# Installing JEDI in Delphi CE 10.3 Rio, no CE version tab in the installer

Tags: delphi, jedi

When installing JVCl349/JCL27, the installer app that is created does not create a tab for RAD Studio XE10 CE 10.3 Rio.
I have tried clean.bat and dumping all existing JEDI bpls.
How can I get JEDI installed in CE 10.3?

Comment: How are you getting the JVCL/JCL?  When I used the instructions from the github page (https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl) by cloning and running install.bat, it gets installed into my 10.3 Community Edition.

Comment: There is no technical difference between Delphi 10.3 Rio Professional and Delphi 10.3 Rio Community. There is only a legal difference (i.e. the license). So what installs for the normal 10.3 should install for CE. But if you can, use git and clone the repositories, first JCL and then JVCL, and also install them in that order, using the install.bat files that can be found in these repositories. That should work.